# How do I include tax and discount in computed field?

Tags: entities, commerce

I use the [Commerce price by components](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components) module to display products' commerce_price field with tax and [discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) included.
It works as expected (I'm displaying the products' prices with a view in a panel)

I have another field, which is a [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field), that I use to calculate the discount between the commerce_price field and a custom price field (MSRP).

**Unfortunately**, while the commerce_price is displayed with tax and discount included, the value sent to the computed field (from the commerce_price token) is the original value, without tax or discount applied, or any information related to the price components.

I can't figure out a clean way to apply the tax and the discount to the commerce_field value used for the calculation in the *Computed field*. How can I make the computed field receive the same token value as the one displayed?

I'm aware of the module [Drupal Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) but using the [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) gives me way more flexibility to calculate discount and special prices captions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprising I did not find this function before, but this is what I needed:

[commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($product, $precalc = FALSE)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product_pricing!commerce_product_pricing.module/function/commerce_product_calculate_sell_price/7)

Returns a price field data array as returned by entity_metadata_wrapper().